# passing fstream object as function parameter in C++, causes file truncation

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am trying to pass an `fstream` object as a function parameter. I have a file `"testing.txt"` and I want to open the file using following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void myFunc(fstream &myFile, char* filename)
{
    myFile.open(filename, 'r');
    if (!myFile)
    {
        perror("Something went wrong");
        exit(0);
    }
}


int main()
{
    fstream myFile;
    myFunc(myFile, "testing.txt");
    //DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE OPENED FILE
    //AND CLOSE THE FILE IN THE END

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I typed and saved some words in `"testing.txt"`, `file size = 93 Bytes`. But after running this code, everything from the file disappears and file size becomes `0 Bytes`. It is like, any content that existed in the file, has now been discarded. And hence this file becomes useless. I have also tried passing `ifstream object` instead of `fstream object`, but no luck. *I am missing something, or making mistakes, please help me to figure it out*.

PS: I need a function to open file and look for errors, I am opening several files in my project.

PPS: I have gone through similar questions on `stackoverflow`, but none of them had this issue. And the file sizes (mentioned above) are as shown in windows explorer. And I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1

Comment: The second parameter of `fstream::open` is **not** a character. It's a set of flags. The ASCII code of `'r'` is interpreted as some combination of those flags. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out which flags you are inadvertently passing, but I bet `ios::out` is one of them.

Comment: i moved to C++ after learning C (in which we do pass "r" for opening in reading mode). I mistakenly assumed that I can still pass "r" for opening in reading mode. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!